# Containing a Rectangle inside another Rectangle

Tags: python, pyqt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I didn't find a previous question that seemed to suit what I am asking, but I may not be asking the right thing either.

I have two rectangles, one larger and one smaller. The smaller one can be moved and resized, but I need it contained inside the larger one. But I am having a hard time keeping it inside of the larger one. I can detect when it moves outside of the larger rectangle, but I cannot figure out the method needed to keep it contained without moving outside of the bounding box.

I am currently working python/pyqt4 in a qgraphicsview/scene.

For a working example: In the program gimp, the cropping tool box cannot move outside of the image that is displayed. But it can be moved and resized up to the image's size. That's what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Are you continuously getting callbacks as the size or location changes?  Obviously if you only get an event once the final location is set, then all you can do is test if it's outside the bounds and bust the user then.  If you're getting callbacks as the size changes, just do the same test and push back to the previous known good state.

Comment: @NickBastin I do get continuous updates. That was much easier then what I was trying to do, though it does 'stick' against a side now. It also doesn't always go to the edge of the larger rect as the mouse movements may be larger then the updates. But at least this gives me a starting point to refine it now.